# How can I use `caff` to sign some keys at cert-level 2 and some at cert-level 3?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I participated in two key sharing parties last week. Upon return, I tried to certify the keys of the participants that I had verified. For creating the signatures, I use `caff` from the `signing-party` package. I only verified that key, email address and UID belong together for some participants, others showed me their ID additionally. I want to issue signatures of cert-level 2 for the former, and cert-level 3 for the ones whose IDs I checked.

I have a separate keyring file for each of the events. I used `caff -R --key-file <fp1 fp2…fpn>`, to ensure that the keys would be imported from the files that were shared at the event. I tried:

- Just using caff and when asked whether I want to sign for a specific UID:
  *I was not asked for the certification level*
- Checking whether I can add `--ask-cert-level` to the `caff` call:
  *couldn't find anything to that effect in the man and didn't succeed when tried*
- Declining to sign when asked whether I want to sign a UID by `caff`, but then adding a signature manually while in the key-edit mode before saving:
  *I could not figure out how to set a cert-level in the `gpg --edit-key` dialogue*
- Signing the key with `--ask-for-cert` in the event-specific key-ring before calling  `caff` on it:
  *while `caff` did recognize that I had previously signed some other keys in the ring and told me that there was nothing to do for me, it did not tell me that for the keys I had manually created a sig3 on before calling `caff`.*

Is there a way to use `caff` to create some `sig2` and some `sig3` on different keys, or to do two separate runs to create `sig2` on one set of fingerprints, then do another run to create `sig3` for other fingerprints? I am okay with manually creating the `sig3`s, but I would like to make use of the automatic export by UID, encryption and mailing that `caff` performs.

Comment: While writing up my question, I came across the parameter `gpg-sign-args` which I'll try when I get back home tonight. If that works, I'll write my own answer, but would be of course happy to see someone else's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem through the discovery of `pius`, a newer python-based PGP singing tool. Pius asks explicitly what cert-level to apply for each key and was available directly from the package manager. It also sidestepped the horrible requirement of setting up a MTA by sending the signed public keys via SMTP.